# How to echo the actual file names represented by * in bash

Tags: bash

Suppose I have a list of files such like:

```
C92LDANXX_s8_1_A01_0337_SL152928.fastq.gz
C92LDANXX_s8_1_A02_0242_SL152929.fastq.gz
C92LDANXX_s8_2_A01_0337_SL152928.fastq.gz
C92LDANXX_s8_2_A02_0242_SL152929.fastq.gz
```

And I have a for loop:

```
for sample in {0337,0242}
do
    f1=*_1_*_${sample}_*.fastq.gz
    f2=*_2_*_${sample}_*.fastq.gz
    echo $f1
    echo $f2
done
```

It will echo as:

```
*_1_*_0337_*.fastq.gz
*_2_*_0337_*.fastq.gz
..
```

My question is, since the $f1 and $f2 are unique, how to echo the full actual names of $f1 and $f2 such as:

```
C92LDANXX_s8_1_A01_0337_SL152928.fastq.gz
C92LDANXX_s8_2_A01_0337_SL152928.fastq.gz 
..
```

Comment: If `echo $1` emits the glob expression itself, that means there **are no** filenames the glob expands to.

Comment: Also, you've got a bunch of quoting-related bugs. In general, it's unsafe to store globs in string variables, because they can't be expanded in a way that doesn't also perform string-splitting unless you modify IFS; it's much safer to store the *results* of the glob in an array.

Comment: Thanks! Since I have hundreds of files like these, I was trying to find a good way to loop thru instead of changing file names or typing. Any suggestions?

Comment: I am maybe looked very elementary to bash but not sure why someone gave me a -1. I have done my best to make the question clear enough

Comment: My assumption, though it's only an assumption, is that the downvote is related to the issue title claiming a bug / shell behavior that doesn't actually exist. (Note how my answer *creates the files* before demonstrating glob behavior in those files' presence -- that way it's a proper self-contained [mcve], so anyone can copy/paste and see results without having to do anything to create files beforehand or clean up afterwards).

Comment: `for i in \`ls -1 | egrep "0337|0242"\`; do echo $i; done`

Comment: @TuncayGöncüoğlu, that's **very** buggy. See [BashPitfalls #1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_i_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29), and [Don't Read Lines With For](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor).

Comment: @TuncayGöncüoğlu, ...and also see [Why you shouldn't parse the output of `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy not in this case, nope. file names in question dont contain spaces and ls -1 gives a neat list, so, this will work.

Comment: @TuncayGöncüoğlu, sure, it'll work with the sample data given here, but if the code would only be run with these exact four filenames, then there'd be no need to run `ls` at all, they could just be hardcoded.

Comment: @TuncayGöncüoğlu, moreover -- one of the worst data loss events I've been present for was caused by filenames that "couldn't happen" (a bad pointer being followed in a C extension to a Python library caused garbage to be dumped into filenames, and someone writing a script to clean up old backups assumed that since the code was only supposed to create names matching `[0-9a-f]{24}` that they didn't need to quote).

Comment: @TuncayGöncüoğlu, ...that cleanup script deleted multiple TB of backups of records used for billing. You don't know when making assumptions will bite you -- the safe thing is to *always* do the job right.

Comment: sorry to hear that charles, but my comment is only directed to the specific question above, so other considerations dont really apply.

Comment: @TuncayGöncüoğlu, we're teaching people practices they'll use throughout their careers. Other considerations **absolutely** apply.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148798/discussion-between-tuncay-goncuoglu-and-charles-duffy).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your own code should actually work as-given for the specific filenames below. However, it has numerous quoting-related bugs. The below both fixes those bugs, and creates empty files with your given names (inside a temporary directory) to demonstrate that the glob expansion **does** actually work.

---

```
tempdir=$(mktemp -d test.XXXXXX)
touch "$tempdir"/{C92LDANXX_s8_1_A01_0337_SL152928,C92LDANXX_s8_1_A02_0242_SL152929,C92LDANXX_s8_2_A01_0337_SL152928,C92LDANXX_s8_2_A02_0242_SL152929}.fastq.gz

cd "$tempdir" || { rm -rf "$tempdir"; exit 1; }

for sample in {0337,0242}; do
    f1=( *_1_*_"${sample}"_*.fastq.gz )
    if [ -e "${f1[0]}" ] || [ -L "${f1[0]}" ]; then
      echo "f1 matches for $sample:"
      printf '  %q\n' "${f1[@]}"
    else
      echo "No f1 matches for $sample found"
    fi

    f2=( *_2_*_"${sample}"_*.fastq.gz )
    if [ -e "${f2[0]}" ] || [ -L "${f2[0]}" ]; then
      echo "f2 matches for $sample:"
      printf '  %q\n' "${f2[@]}"
    else
      echo "No f2 matches for $sample found"
    fi
done

rm -rf -- "$tempdir"
```

...properly emits the output:

```
f1 matches for 0337:
  C92LDANXX_s8_1_A01_0337_SL152928.fastq.gz
f2 matches for 0337:
  C92LDANXX_s8_2_A01_0337_SL152928.fastq.gz
f1 matches for 0242:
  C92LDANXX_s8_1_A02_0242_SL152929.fastq.gz
f2 matches for 0242:
  C92LDANXX_s8_2_A02_0242_SL152929.fastq.gz
```

---

Note:

- All variable expansions are quoted. This means that they expand to their literal contents -- otherwise, filenames containing characters in IFS would be split into multiple pieces, and filenames containing glob character literals would be glob-expanded.
- Glob results are stored in an array, and those arrays are expanded with `"${arrayname[@]}"`. See [the BashGuide on Arrays](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Arrays).
- `"${f1[0]}"` expands to the first element in array `f1`. If this either exists (`test -e`) or is a link (`test -L`), then we know that the glob actually expanded, and thus that at least one match exists in the current directory.
- `printf '%q\n'` prints filenames in `eval`-safe form (so the content could be copied-and-pasted back into the shell, and would be treated as the filename's exact value). To instead print it in literal form (followed by a newline), use `printf '%s\n'` instead. Note that on most UNIX filesystems, filenames are allowed to contain newline literals, so storing them unescaped in newline-separated (as opposed to NUL-delimeted) form is not ideal.